# How to touch up surface painted with airless sprayer

Tags: painting, paint, spraypainting, spray-paint

I painted a steel door with an airless sprayer - the finish looked wonderful! Unfortunately I scratched the door while re-installing it on the hinges. Now the question is how to address the scratch. If I brush paint over it, presumably it will stick out like a sore thumb? Do I have to sand around the scratch and "spot re-spray"? Or do I have to spray the full door again?

---- EDIT ----
I tried to brush with Purdy XL brush and the red paint with some Floetrol:

[image]

In the top left you can see some brush marks, and near the lock you can see a big "dip" where the old paint has been sanded through (it's a brand new door - it's not like there were 20 years of paint on it, so I'm kind of surprised the first layers of red paint are so thick). I'm in the "it looks good enough" camp, but I'm still trying to get a consensus out how you'd do it "right". I don't think spraying instead of brushing would have helped with the hard edges of old paint layer?

Comment: is it possible to see a picture just to get an idea of the size, shape, and color?

Comment: @depperm I can post a picture tonight. It's bright red, and a single thin scratch maybe about 4" long. I guess I'm interested in this more generally too as I'm preparing for more scratches that kids will put in this door over time :).

Comment: Kids? Ah well, plan to re-spray after 4 years...

Answer (score 3):

28 years of experience as a painter .. what works best is a light sanding and then a very light dusting of the enamel spray paint .  May require 2 light coats ..  it is tricky and you will have to be very light handed with this so you don't create a noticeable " patched "area.  Good Luck!

Comment: how do I get spray paint to match the latex paint color?

Comment: I assumed he means using the airless sprayer not a can